# Find by association (Datamapper)

Tags: ruby, database, datamapper, relationship

I've got two models that look like this

```
class Stage
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    belongs_to :staff
end

class Staff
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, String, :key => true 
  property  :full_name, String 
  property  :email, String
  has n, :stages
end
```

I'm trying to find all Stages that have a specific Staff member assigned. I've tried     `@stages = Stage.all(Stage.Staff => 'TM')`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, its been a while since i used DataMapper.

```
Stage.all(Stage.staff.id => 'TM')
```

This is assuming that the 'TM' would actually be the value you use for the id of the staff member.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can use string keys in datamapper like this:

```
Stage.all('staff.id' => 'TM')
```

or

```
Stage.all('staff.name.like' => 'Ted%')
```

You can mix and match with properties in that model as well:

```
Stage.all('staff.name.like' => 'Ted%', 'id.gte' => 5 )
```

That'll get all of the Stages belonging to people whose names start with 'Ted' and have an id greater than or equal to 5.

Comment: To be clear, the % is SQL partial string matching syntax. You could also have done Stage.all('staff.name' => /^Ted/) as well :) and DataMapper is smart enough to know how to do the matching/translation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do

```
@stages = Stage.all(:staff => 'TM')
```

Comment: It does not return an error, but does not return any data either. If I run it on other fields such as title, it works ok, but not for the foreign key?

Comment: @Tom I cannot test it, I'd suggest to try to indicate the association with :links e.g. `Stage.all(:links => [ :staff], Stage.staff.id => 'TM')`